# Leading whitespace hover underline on privileges page

Tags: bug, design, css

On the [page that lists privileges](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), hovering over items in that list cause a single underscore/whitespace underline to appear before each group of text:

[image: This site's Privilege List]

This does not appear to happen on some of the other SE sites I've checked (Stack Overflow, SE meta, and Worldbuilding):
[image: StackOverflow's Privilege List]

The issue persisted across both Chrome (v 52.0.2743.116 m) and Firefox (v 47) with all extensions disabled.

Comment: The difference is that `a:hover` is set to `text-decoration: underline` in `all.css` for this site, but not for SO. The anchor wraps div tags, and the line breaks get rendered as spaces, which then get underlined on hover. This can be overridden in CSS easily.

Comment: This problem is not specific to the privileges page. The double underline on all the tabs on the user activity page looks pretty bad too.